# Restrict unauthorized users from downloading the apk in Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I am planning to drop my app in Google Play(earlier Android Market) because of push notifications (whenever a new version) , security for apk and so on.And also since apk is secured with Google play(paid apks) i dropped of downloading the apk from my website (only authenticated people can download the apk)

Actually its a business app for particular users with username and login access. Everything was fine in the App with login and security mechanisms

**I am thinking of a way to restrict the other users who are not from the list while installing itself.** 
My question is whether any kind of filter or authentication mechanism can we set while downloading the application from the Google play it should ask for a password or something like this to filter the unauthorized users to download the app..

My ultimate aim is i don't want the peoples to try it after downloading unnecessarily

Can anybody help who have tried all those in android market

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok.. One thing after another..

- Google propose [their licensing mechanism](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/licensing/index.html). However app would need internet connection, which is disadvantage if otherwise it doesn't need it. If I got it right your does need to connect to server so this is not a problem for u.. It seems to me you are already familiar with this method.
- Mechanism for password protecting downloading or visibility of apps on Google Play doesn't exist today..
- You can identify users with IMEI (in case you don't consider using app on tablets, which doesn't have it), WLAN MAC, BT MAC address or some exotic combination of these methods, and you use this as authentication.
- The best solution, from my point of view, is to allow people on market to download it. Your application is already using some mechanism of authentication (user/password) to server. So if 1st thing user need to do is login, and any functionality is disabled if that doesn't pass. If it pass, you already know who is your user and what privileges he has.

The thing is here that I am not so sure what are your concerns when user without login/pass download application if everything after that screen is disabled before authentication. User will download (if they find it..), they will install, try to use it, see that's not possible without credentials and uninstall it.

Hope it helped.. I will try to add few more links in a while..

Comment: @eworks : Thanks !! I gone through several websites regarding Google play. I want to make sure if there are any kind of mechanisms before downloading is there or not !! From your answer its clear No Not possible Thanks you so much