# Restrict users from downloading APK file from google play store

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I have made an android app and want to upload it to play store,which will be available for all users if they want to install it in their android devices.But I don't want any one to download my APK(using chrome extension and other websites),decompile it and pose any security threat to my API's

I found some links,but were not much helpful

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828121/restrict-unauthorized-users-from-downloading-the-apk-in-google-play)

Comment: Impossible. Whenever people download your app to their device, they download the actual .apk. With root, this apk is easily retrieved. The only thing you can do is do exactly what your linked answer states.

Answer (score 1):

try using

The `PackageManager` class that supplies the `getInstallerPackageNam`e method that will tell you the package name of whatever installed the package you specify. Side-loaded apps will not contain a value.

And apparently the latest version of the Amazon store finally sets `PackageManager.getInstallerPackageName()` to `"com.amazon.venezia"` as well to contrast with Google Play's `"com.android.vending"`.